# Using empty char as loop condition, program ends when it is supposed to loop

Tags: java

> This program is supposed to loop for an input of a char if nothing is written in, the program will however not compile, it does not accept char tegn='';. How can i create a loop where the condition si that nothing has been written in for a char?

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
       char tegn = '';
        do {
        tegn = showInputDialog("Input a char.").charAt(0);
        } while (tegn == '');
```

Update:
I solved my code with an idea from the code of Vishal K, using String to determine if the user wrote in nothing or something:

```
    String tegn = ""; 
do { tegn = showInputDialog("Input a char."); 
} while (tegn.equals("")); 

char chartegn = tegn.charAt(0);
```

Comment: after 1 loop, it'll obviously end right? Unless you keep providing `space` as input.

Comment: use `while(tegn=='')` instead

Comment: ah derp, yes, it does, so it works as written, but how about if i simply press enter, cause if i write in char tegn = ''; it will not compile at all

Comment: @user2202185 what is input dialog? text on console? swing? swt? somethink else? looks like JOptionPane.showInputDialog() but... post more details.

Comment: import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

Comment: @Rune yes, i see now, sorry :)

Comment: Do you want to check the condition on if tegn is a `spacebar` ? or when user puts nothing in `InputDialog` and just press enter.?

Comment: I wish it to loop when absolutely nothing is entered

Comment: If use enters nothing and press enter then In that case you must be getting exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because in that case you are trying to extract our character at index 0 out of the String which has nothing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
    String str = "";
    char tegn=' ';
    do {
     str = showInputDialog("Input a char.");
     if (str != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(str.trim()))
     {
       tegn = str.charAt(0);
     }
    }while(str!=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(str.trim())
```

Comment: I will try something like this, 1 moment

Comment: Alright so I did this and it worked, though i didn't quite understand your code i tried out just using string all the way and when loop is done(user input something for char), i converted the first symbol in the string to the char which is going to be used, AFTER the loop:   String tegn = "";
  do {
  tegn = showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tegn.");
 } while (tegn.equals(""));
 char chartegn = tegn.charAt(0);

Comment: .equalsIgnoreCase(str.trim()))  <--- Don't know even know what this does, but I will do some reflecting on it now after i finally made a code that worked for it's purpose. I am fairly new to programming. On a sidenote THANKS for all the awesome help/feedback I did not expect this to be so quickly answered, will use this website more for sure.

Comment: You are most welcome to StackOverflow . :) `str.trim()` removes the leading and trailing spaces from the input `String`. And `"".equalsIgnoreCase(str.trim())` checks if the string returned by `str.trim()` is blank . If it is it returns true else false. Look at here to know about `String` and its various methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Is it possible to edit the answer after accepted? If so maybe you could paste in "my solution" as well, whatever looks best for other ppl who are visiting and can see what a solution can be made

Comment: You can post your own answer separately in this post and tell people how is it your working solution. And if you feel that your own answer is much better than mine then u can unaccept my answer by clicking on tick sign again and accept your answer . very simple .:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you just press enter when prompt for input you are sending a character return and not a space (' ').

i would suggest checking if the input is less than a center ascii value (space and every symbol, and character start at DEC 32)

ie. you can convert your char value to an integer value.
(int ascii = (int) character)

and use this to validate your input.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Trying to work on the converting to int thingie, so far i got: char tegn;
  do {
  tegn = showInputDialog("Write a char.").charAt(0);
  int ascii = Integer.parseInt(tegn);
 } while (ascii < 33);

Comment: are you still having the same problem ?

Comment: Yes, it's hard for me to get it right without getting errors in compilation using this method, trying a different aproach with string/char atm